# Gridview, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, linkbutton

I can't find the source for this problem. I debugged my code and it ends fine and it does what it's requested(deletion of a page entry from the database), however it returns this after the code ends:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDLCH.png

The code for ListPages.aspx is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ListPages.aspx.cs" Inherits="TopStart.admin.ListPages" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
                <div id="container" runat="server" class="full_w">
                <div class="h_title">Manage Your Pages</div>
                <h2>Page Management</h2>
                <p>This is a list of all your website pages. Use the icons on the last column to perform various operations on a page.</p>

            <div class="entry">
                <div class="sep"></div>
            </div>
            <asp:GridView ID="PageList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="PageList_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="PageList_PageIndexChanging">
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
            </asp:GridView>

            <div class="entry">
                <div class="sep"></div>     
                <a class="button add" href="AddPage.aspx">Add new page</a> <a class="button" href="">Categories</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

The code for ListPages.apsx.cs:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TopStart.admin
{
    public partial class ListPages : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                CreatePageList();
        }

    protected void CreatePageList()
    {
        Database db = new Database("mySqlCon");

        string query = "SELECT p.id, p.title, p.slug, u.username, c.categories FROM pages as p LEFT JOIN users AS u ON p.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON p.category_id = c.id";

        DataTable dt = db.Query(query);
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Modify"));

        PageList.DataSource = dt;
        PageList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void PageList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[5].Width = new Unit("65px");
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink edit = new HyperLink();
            edit.NavigateUrl = "EditPage.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            edit.CssClass = "table-icon edit";
            edit.Attributes.Add("title", "Edit");

            HyperLink archive = new HyperLink();
            archive.NavigateUrl = "Archive.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            archive.CssClass = "table-icon archive";
            archive.Attributes.Add("title", "Archive");

            LinkButton delete = new LinkButton();
            delete.CssClass = "table-icon delete";
            delete.Attributes.Add("title", "Delete");
            delete.Attributes.Add("id", e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
            delete.ID = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            delete.Click += new EventHandler(delete_Click);

            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(edit);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(archive);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(delete);
        }
    }

    protected void PageList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        PageList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        PageList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;

        Database db = new Database("mySqlCon");
        string query = "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id = @id";

        MySqlParameter pId = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4);
        pId.Value = lb.ID;

        if (db.MQuery(query, pId))
        {
            container.InnerHtml = "<div class=\"h_title\">Success</div>\n<div class=\"n_ok\"><p>Page was deleted. Redirecting...</p></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            container.InnerHtml = "<div class=\"h_title\">Failure</div>\n<div class=\"n_error\"><p>Page couldn't be deleted. Redirecting...</p></div>";
        }

        Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "3;URL=ListPages.aspx");
    }
}
```

}

I think there's something wrong with the GridView. When the delete button is clicked my code doesn't go straight to the event method but goes to PageLoad again, renders the GridView again (supposedly, in the code) and then goes to the method event. Please help me I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `CreatePageList` in `if(!IsPostBack)`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        CreatePageList();
}
```

The complete lifecycle is run through on every postback. That is normal. However, you should not databind the grid to it's DataSource from `Page_Load` on every postback if ViewState is enabled(default). Do that only if something has changed, so for example **after** you have deleted a row from the delete-event.

Otherwise all changes are lost since the previous values are loaded from database, also events aren't triggered anymore.

**Update** You are also creating controls dynamically in `RowDataBound`. That is not a good place, use `RowCreated` instead.   Dynamic controls must be recreated on every postback. But `RowDataBound` is called only if the `GridView` is databound which is not necessarily on every postback. As opposed to this `RowCreated` *is* called on every postback.

But since you are setting the `NavigateUrl` in `RowDataBound` which is derived from an `ID` of the underlying `DataItem` you have to create the `Hyperlink` in `RowCreated` as mentioned with an appropriate `ID`. Use this `ID` in `RowDataBound` to find the `Hyperlink` and set it's `NavigateUrl` property.

The important point is that it will be recreated always, but it's `NavigateUrl` property is set just once.

Comment: In his code he is replacing content of `div` (id = container) in which he placed `GridView` so is grid view removed from page life cycle as well? I think that is why he is getting exception.

Comment: @gzaxx: He should create the dynamic control in `RowCreated` and set itheir properties that depend on the datasource from `RowDataBound`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Can't I do everything in RowCreated? I just tried and it doesn't render the controls. So how do I set an appropriate ID to RowCreated and then use it at RowDataBound, I'm confused here. And yes, when the delete event method is fired, I change the container HTML to a success message then redirect again to the same page to show the GridView again.

Comment: @GlendGjermeni: You cannot do all in `RowCreated` since you have no `DataSource` there, both, `GridView.DataSource` and `e.Row.DataItem` are null on postbacks. You can chose what you want as `ID`, e.g. `edit.Id = "editLink"`. Then in `RowDataBound`: `var editLink = (Hyperlink)e.Row.FindControl("editLink");`. Use `e.Row.DataItem` in `RowDataBound` to get all your data for this row.

Comment: Wouldn't I be giving the same ID to all edit controls for several rows?

Comment: @GlendGjermeni: That is not a problem since ASP.NET will automatically create unique id's for the rendered controls to the client. They will be derived from the `NamingContainer` of each control. That is the `GridViewRow` here. So controls must have an unique (server-)ID only in a `GridViewRow`, the rows itself can repeat. Otherwise it would be difficult to give repeating controls an ID ;-)

Comment: I did this changes http://pastebin.com/KsMFh8ad but it's giving me a NullReferenceException on line 48, the edit control is null it seems. Also, how do I use e.Row.DataItem instead of Cells, sorry for asking but I'm new in ASP.Net.

Comment: @GlendGjermeni: The `NamingContainer` of your controls is not the `Page` but the `GridViewRow`, so replace `Page.FindControl("editLink")` with `e.Row.FindControl("editLink")`. You can get the `DataRow` from the `GridViewRow` via `e.Row.DataItem` in this way: `DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;`. Then you have all you need to get all fields from it, e.g.: `int id = row.Field<int>("id");`

Comment: I tried both e.Row.FindControl and e.Row.Cells[5].FindControl as here http://pastebin.com/BBXCbftw but it still gives that exception.